# State Price Densities vs PDF of Payoffs in Ait-Sahalia (1998)

Tags: options, probability, pricing

At the start of section I in the paper, the authors talk about the difference between the SPD/risk-neutral PDF/equivalent martingale measure vs the PDF of payoffs. I understand that the SPD is used in computing the price of the financial security through a discounted net PV approach, but what exactly does the author mean by PDF of payoffs? Are the two not the same?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but looking through, it looks like the author is mostly writing about the SPD (or risk-neutral pdf). When they refer to the pdf of payoffs, I think they mean the physical measure pdf.